# Validating php within html tags

Tags: php, html

I have a registration page that uses both html and php I wish to validate the ALL user information before he recieves this alert >> **Your ID number and password will send to your email address when the casher confirm your enrollment**

Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>

</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.ed{
border-style:solid;
border-width:thin;
border-color:#00CCFF;
padding:5px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
}
#button1{
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-style:solid;
border-width:thin;
border-color:#00CCFF;
padding:5px;
background-color:#00CCFF;
height: 34px;
}
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
  {
  alert("Your ID number and password will send to your email address when the casher confirm your enrollment");
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainwrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <img src="images/amuni.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="loginform.php">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="pre_reg.php">Student Pre Registration</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="help.php">Help</a>
                </li>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="padding:20px; text-align:justify; font-family:arial;">

<form action="save_pre_reg.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
Firstname <br />
<input name="fname" type="text" class="ed" id="brnu" />
<br>
Lastname <br />
<input name="lname" type="text" class="ed" id="brnu" />
<br>
Middlename <br />
<input name="mname" type="text" class="ed" id="brnu" />
<br>
Gender<br />
<select name="gender" class="ed">
<option>Male</option>
<option>Female</option>
</select>
<br>
Email<br />
<input name="email" type="text" class="ed" id="brnu" />
<br>
Address <br />
<textarea name="address" class="ed"></textarea>
<br>
Age<br />
<input name="age" type="text" class="ed" id="brnu" />
<br>
Birthday<br />
<select name="month" class="ed">
<option>Month</option>
<?php
$N = 13;
for($i=1; $i < $N; $i++)
{
echo '<option>'.$i.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
/
<select name="day" class="ed">
<option>Days</option>
<?php
$N = 32;
for($i=1; $i < $N; $i++)
{
echo '<option>'.$i.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
/
<select name="year" class="ed">
<option>Year</option>
<?php
$N = 2020;
for($i=1889; $i < $N; $i++)
{
echo '<option>'.$i.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<br>
Level<br />
<select name="level" class="ed">
<option>Grade 1</option>
<option>Grade 2</option>
<option>Grade 3</option>
<option>Grade 4</option>
<option>Grade 5</option>
<option>Grade 6</option>
<option>1st year</option>
<option>2nd year</option>
<option>3rd year</option>
<option>4th year</option>
</select>
<br>
Payment Mode<br />
<select name="paymode" class="ed">
<option>Full Payment</option>
<option>Installment</option>
</select>
<br>
Family Income (monthly)<br />
<select name="fincome" class="ed">
<option>12,000 - 19,000</option>
<option>20,000 - 29,000</option>
<option>30,000 - 39,000</option>
<option>40,000 - 49,000</option>
<option>50,000 - 59,000</option>
<option>60,000 - 69,000</option>
<option>70,000 - 79,000</option>
<option>80,000 - 89,000</option>
<option>90,000 - 99,000</option>
<option>100,000 - above</option>
</select>
<br>
Mother's Name <br />
<input name="moname" type="text" class="ed" id="brnu" />
<br>
Occupation <br />
<input name="moccu" type="text" class="ed" id="brnu" />
<br>
Father's Name <br />
<input name="faname" type="text" class="ed" id="brnu" />
<br>
Occupation <br />
<input name="foccu" type="text" class="ed" id="brnu" />
<br>
Religion <br />
<input name="religiom" type="text" class="ed" id="brnu" />
<br>
School Year<br>
<select name="syear" class="ed">
<option>School Year</option>
<?php
$N = 2020;
for($i=1991; $i < $N; $i++)
{
$p=$i+1;
echo '<option>'.$i.'-'.$p.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="save" id="button1" />
</form>
</div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my save_reg page

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str)
    {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
            }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }
//Sanitize the POST values
$fname = clean($_POST['fname']);
$lname = clean($_POST['lname']);
$mname = clean($_POST['mname']);
$email = clean($_POST['email']);
$gender = clean($_POST['gender']);
$status = 'pending';
$bday = clean($_POST['month']).'/'.clean($_POST['day']).'/'.clean($_POST['year']);
$level = clean($_POST['level']);
$paymode = clean($_POST['paymode']);
$fincome = clean($_POST['fincome']);
$moname = clean($_POST['moname']);
$moccu = clean($_POST['moccu']);
$faname = clean($_POST['faname']);
$foccu = clean($_POST['foccu']);
$sec='none';
$ppic='images/profic.png';
$add = clean($_POST['address']);
$age = clean($_POST['age']);
$religiom = clean($_POST['religiom']);
$syear = clean($_POST['syear']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tuetion WHERE level='$level'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        if ($paymode=='Full Payment'){
        $payables=($row['payable']-($row['payable']*.05));
        }
        else if ($paymode=='Installment'){
        $payables=$row['payable'];
        }
        }
mysql_query("INSERT INTO prereg (fname, lname, mname, level, gender, paymentmode, payable, mother, m_occupation, father, f_occopation, family_income, section, status, email, bday, address, age, religion, ppic, schoolyear)
VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$mname','$level','$gender','$paymode','$payables','$moname','$moccu','$faname','$foccu','$fincome','$sec','$status','$email','$bday','$add','$age','$religiom','$ppic','$syear')");
header("location: pre_reg.php");
?>
```

it saves data but saves even blanks I want it to validate, before inserting

Comment: What have you already tried? Also, you can't use the same id multiple times.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Fix your form. You can be born 31 february 1889 and still enroll.

Comment: An `if statement` will do the job for you, 
     `var brnu = $('#brnu').val();
     if (name == "") {
      alert ('You didn't fill this field!')
     }`

& by the way You could only post your form tag & its fields

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*`, but prepared statements instead, with MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a name on your form:

```
<form action="save_pre_reg.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="registrationform">
```

Validate the form before sending:

```
function validateForm()
{
  if (document.registrationform.fname == '') {
      alert('Please type your first name');
      return false;
  }
  else if (document.registrationform.lname == '') {
      alert('Please type your first name');
      return false;
  }
  // more conditions here
  else {
  alert("Your ID number and password will send to your email address when the casher confirm your enrollment");
  return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @ milian works nicely, @bart i dont understand jquery still returns a blank but no alert, but it working now thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a simple (e.g. jQuery) solution, if you don't want to use a plugin:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function() {
    var form = $(this);

    if (form.find("input[name=fname]").val() == '') {
        alert('Error: FNAME is empty!');
        return false; // important
    }

    // more validation
});
```

By the way:

- Don't use the `id`-attribute several times with the same value. It has to be unique. Otherwise use the `class`-attribute.
- Only post relevant code (form + js) next time
- Validate your HTML.

Good luck!